# How to add the server name in monitor results Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

By default when we add monitor results at that time it will not show any host name. How can we add the sever name. Anyone can please explain it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to export the server you are sending requqests to in your results file?

Answer (score 1):

PerfMon Metrics Collector doesn't do any auto-discovery of [Server Agents](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonAgent/), you have to specify hostnames or IP addresses of servers you want to monitor manually like:

1. Click "Add Row" button
2. Provide server hostname or IP address, port and desired metric
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for all servers you want to monitor

   [image: PerfMon Metrics Collector]

When you start your test you'll be able to see server hostnames or IP addresses in upper-left corner of the generated chart:

[image: PerfMon Sampling]

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) guide for end-to-end instructions on setting up server-side performance monitoring in your JMeter test

Comment: Thanks, But i am asking about "Montior Results" option which is directly available in the listeners